# I have a Terra-Master F4-210 NAS & Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop edition. All I want to do is setup a network drive so I can access my files from any local PC

Tags: networking, mount, samba, nas

06/22/2021

Hi there, I am looking for help. I want to access my Network Attached Storage (NAS) Terra-Master F4-210 on my Ubuntu 20.04 PC to read and write files that may have been stored in other places.

I run Ubuntu, Mint, and Windows 10 Home & Professional. When I create and update my files, every system has its own version of the document. It's not always possible to use the same computer, and using USB Sticks is a hassle. With the NAS, all the devices could access the same file and keep the document current without any issues. The software included in the Terra-Master Operation System (TOS) is written for Windows10 and MAC. Nothing for Ubuntu. I also want to take advantage of RAID6 redundancy to stop losing any more documents, as I have done in the past.

I have installed Samba, but honestly don't have a clue how to configure it. Most of the searches I've found are for "how to make centralized file storage on Ubuntu." This isn't what I want and defeats the purpose of having a NAS device.

All I want to do is to configure Ubuntu to access my NAS drive, so I store my files there instead of on a Local PC.

Comment: Will these Ubuntu machines always be connected to the network, or are they notebooks that can leave the house? With regards to RAID, be aware that deleting a file will still result in that file being "lost". RAID is not a backup, but instead a means to recover from "mild hardware failure" ...

Comment: The "samba" package is for sharing stuff on your Ubuntu machine to others in the network. The samba client libraries are already installed on Ubuntu to access other hosts shares. Please install nmap `sudo apt install nmap` , Run the following command with the correct ip address of the NAS:  `nmap --script smb-protocols 192.168.0.100`. Add the results to your original question.

Comment: nmap --script smb-protocols 192.168.1.120
Starting Nmap 7.80 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-06-24 20:56 MDT
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.120
Host is up (0.012s latency).
Not shown: 988 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
21/tcp    open  ftp
23/tcp    open  telnet
80/tcp    open  http
111/tcp   open  rpcbind
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
443/tcp   open  https
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
548/tcp   open  afp
2049/tcp  open  nfs
8181/tcp  open  intermapper
8300/tcp  open  tmi
49152/tcp open  unknown

Comment: Host script results:
| smb-protocols: 
|   dialects: 
|     NT LM 0.12 (SMBv1) [dangerous, but default]
|     2.02
|     2.10
|     3.00
|     3.02
|_    3.11

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.69 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just bought one of these things on eBay and had to figure this out all on my own.

First, you need to install the OS on the NAS. Then you need to visit the Web interface for it and do a couple of things.

[image]

[image]

Be sure to apply after each one of those. I could not believe FTP was enabled by default. Hellooooo Ransomware!

```
sudo apt-get install samba smbclient cifs-utils nmap samba-common

sudo nano /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

#add min and max lines below
;   bind interfaces only = yes

```
client min protocol = SMB2
client max protocol = SMB3
```

#exit and save

```
sudo systemctl restart smbd.service

mkdir ~/tnas
mkdir ~/bin
nano ~/bin/mount-tnas
```

#add the following line, exit and save

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o uid=$UID,gid=$(id -g),vers=3.0,username=your-user-name-on-NAS '//NAS-ip-address/your-private-directory' /home/your-user-name-on-ubuntu/tnas


chmod +x ~/bin/mount-trans
```

If you did not already have a ~/bin you should probably log out and back in. Then open a terminal and type

```
mount-tnas
```

You can forget about being able to mount this thing through the GUI file utility. Ubuntu is always quite a ways behind when it comes to things like that. This will mount it on demand and make it appear in your GUI file manager.

Comment: Thank you.

I appreciate the info. 

Ya, I just disabled FTP services. 

I added SMB (unknown why it wasn't installed)  

I'm still learning Linux. Most days, I feel pretty dumb. But I'm still playing. 

I was able to open the NAS with file explorer and select "Other Location." Then Connect to Server  SMB://192.xx.xx.xx, and that seemed to work for me. 

I still have no idea how to use the resources (apps) in TOS.

Comment: Upvotes are a great way to say thank you! I never worry about the apps. I've been running file servers for central storage since Netware 2.11 and the 386/SX. I almost set one of my other computers up as a file server running Linux when my other two NAS hit EOL for security updates, then I found this thing on eBay for $200. Next time I will probably just set up a Samba server